# best unix shell on windows?

Tags: windows

I'm using cmder right now, but I wanted something like zsh and I saw that babun was doing that as well.

Any idea of what is the best way to get unix shortcuts and tools (pipe, streams, ssh-keygen, git, xxd, sed, awk, etc...) on windows?

Comment: Questions that ask for the "best of ..." are not a good fit for this type of community.  Perhaps you can better defined what "best" is

Comment: I'm just trying to get some recommandation and get the discussion going. Dunno where else to do that.

Comment: Chat, discussion forums or slant.co

Comment: @David天宇Wong - Software recommendations are not on topic here.  We are not a discussion forum either.  This question could be salvaged if work was put into it.

Answer (score 1):

[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) offer the tools you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin. You can install zsh there too.

But since babun is "Pre-configured Cygwin with a lot of addons", may be it's also worth a try.